# angularjs with ionrangeslider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hidden-field

I am using angularjs and ionrangeslider ( I know there are other sliders but I have to use this one ).

The slider library is defined in an input element and then it hides the input element, draws the slider, and updates the value of the input element as you move the slider.

The problem with angular is that it is not reading the value of the input element (probably because it is hidden). I have read a lot of posts that state that using hidden fields is not the angular way, but I am not sure if they apply to this case.

the code I am using for defining the slider is :

```
<input 
    id="validationPercentage"   
    type="text" 
    name="validationPercentage"
    data-ng-model="campaign.validationPercentage"
    data-postfix="%"
    data-hasGrid="true"
    data-type="single"
    data-step="1"
    data-min="0"
    data-max="100"
    ></input>
```

and the code in my controller is :

```
var newcampaign = new Campaigns({
    description: this.campaign.description,
    validationPercentage : this.campaign.validationPercentage

});
console.log(this.campaign.description);
console.log(this.campaign.validationPercentage);
```

the output is ok for the description field which is a visible text field, but undefined for the validationPercentage.

I may go around it, by directly accessing the input field in the DOM tree, but that is not a nice solution.

Any ideas how can I do this in the Angular way?

Thanks in advance